# Setting interrupt flag on a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

For the below code,

```
static class SleeperThread  extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    int c;
    try {
        c = System.in.read();
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

As mentioned in this [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4514257), If a thread is blocked on IO(`System.in.read();`), then, Can't the interrupt flag be set on that thread, by another thread?

Comment: Yes, it can. The thing is that the `read()` doesn't check for thread interruption.

Comment: @AndyTurner So, the interrupt flag is set, but as java thread interrupts are synchronous in nature unlike hardware interrupts, we need to wait for `read()` to complete.

Comment: Java thread interrupts are *cooperative* in nature: the thread has to check for interruption explicitly, it doesn't just "happen".

Comment: @overexchange don't use interrupts... There are so many operations that don't react on interrupts! (Just like System.in). There's always another way to achieve what you're trying to do!

Comment: @AndyTurner Unlike `Thread.sleep()` that has capability to check for interrupt on it's own?

Comment: `Thread.sleep` doesn't check "on its own". It is implemented to check for interruption explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Since `System.in` doesn't react on Thread interrupts you have to implement something like it yourself.

To do that you can use the method `available()` of the `System.in` (of `InputStream`).

It might look somewhat like this:

```
class ReadWithInterrupt extends Thread{
    private byte[] result = null;
    public byte[] getResult(){
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                if (this.isInterrupted()){
                    System.out.println("An interrupt occurred");
                    break;
                }
                int available = System.in.available();
                if (available>0){
                    result = new byte[available];
                    System.in.read(result, 0, available);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    Thread.sleep(500);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("An interrupt occurred");
        }
    }
}
```